# Angular 2 Stuck on Loading AppComponent content here

Tags: angularjs, typescript, atom-editor

I have been following along to [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJKejcQJqHE) to learn Angular 2. Just after the 33:00 mark, where I import the headerComponent into the app.module.ts, localhost begins perpetually displaying "Loading AppComponent content here". Meanwhile, in the video, the header and content load almost immediately. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './main.html',
})
export class AppComponent  {

}
```

app.headerComponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: './header/header.html',
})
export class headerComponent  {



}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { headerComponent } from './header/app.headerComponent';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, headerComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: did you `bootstrap`ed your `AppComponent`? [Check here](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/main.ts)

Comment: Maybe there is some build error. See the command line. I think you're trying to load header template from a folder called header within header folder. So changing the templateUrl: './header/header.html' to templateUrl: './header.html' might work.

Comment: Thank you TK Omble, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to TK Omble for finding out the issue. There was a build error because I was loading a header template from a folder called header within header folder. Now I changed the templateUrl: './header/header.html' to templateUrl: './header.html' and it works fine.